# What alternatives do I have to VMS to manage different software project dependencies?

Tags: build, virtual-machine, open-source, versioning, build-dependencies

I've begun delving into open source as well as working on my own personal portfolio of projects.

A problem that I've encountered is that one project will require one version of a software package while another will require a different version of that package. Multiply this by the number of different software dependencies (JS framework, server-side language version, database version, web server, etc) it begins to get out of hand quickly.

My current solution is to have a separate VM for each project so that I can maintain a separate environment for each OSS or personal project. However I now have over 10 VMs and this is a pain to use as any time I want to context switch. Also having to re-install IDEs, editors, git, etc is an additional pain.

Is there a good way to manage different projects each with their own specific software version dependencies in an isolated environment?  Or am I basically stuck with creating a new VM every time I want to work with a different project?

Answer (score 0):

Use portable versions of your dependencies.

In Linux this is a lot easier. In Windows you might be able to install various versions of the same software, assuming there are no services involved.